# Why 燃ゆる in a modern slogan?

Tags: classical-japanese

The Kagoshima National Athletic Meet seems to have been postponed indefinitely from 2020 for obvious reasons.

However, I'm more interested in its slogan 燃ゆる感動. 燃ゆる is indeed the 連体形 of 燃ゆ, so I believe this is grammatical in Classical Japanese.

But my question is -- why the archaism? It doesn't seem to fit the theme at all. Alternatively, is 燃ゆる retained in a dialect, and is here to add local colour?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing it's just a style choice to make the slogan sound a bit more impressive